# Java - create HashMap in overloaded constructor call

Tags: java, hashmap, overloading, constructor-overloading

I got a pretty simple question but couldn't find anything so far.

I'm trying to create two class constructors.
The first constructor gets 2 Strings and one HashMap and initializes the class variables.

```
public Foo(String a, String b, HashMap<String, String> c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```

The second constructor should only get the 2 Strings and create a "default"-HashMap.

Usually you just call `this()` with the default-value inside but I could not find a way to do this with a `HashMap`.

```
public Foo(String a, String b) {
    this(a, b, new HashMap<String, String>().put("x", "y").put("f","g"));
}
```

Eclipse marks an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `String` to `HashMap<String,String>`

And otherwise the `this()`-call cannot be the first statement in the function.

```
public Foo(String a, String b) {
    HashMap<String, String> c = new HashMap<String, String>();
    c.put("x", "y");
    c.put("f", "g");
    this(a, b, c);
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Worst case I had to duplicate the code, but I was wondering if there is no better way.

Comment: your reference to `c` will still be the same. you could simply use `this(a, b, new HashMap<String, String>());` as your first statement and go on working with `c`.

Comment: Map<K,V>'s put returns current value (V). Hence you get the TypeMismatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It´s unneccessary to create a local variable of `c`.

You could simply call it like this.

```
public Foo(String a, String b) {
    this(a, b, new HashMap<String, String>());
    c.put("x", "y");
    c.put("f", "g");
}
```

Since your other constructor `this(String, String, HashMap<String, String>())`
will assign the new `HashMap` to `c` invoking methods on `c` will also fill this newly created `HashMap` and will assign the default values that you did provide to it.

Another solution could be to create a static method and just call it

```
public static HashMap<String, String> createDefaultHashMap() {
    HashMap<String, String> c = new HashMap<String, String>();
    c.put("x", "y");
    c.put("f", "g");
    return c;
}

public Foo(String a, String b) {
    this(a, b, Foo.createDefaultHashMap());;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If this Map is a constant, you could store it as a constant and reuse it. This avoids recreation of the Map each time a new `Foo` is created but it is then shared across all `Foo`s.

```
public class Foo {

    private static final Map<String, String> DEFAULT = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        DEFAULT.put("x", "y");
        DEFAULT.put("f","g");
    }

    public Foo(String a, String b) {
        this(a, b, DEFAULT);
    }

    public Foo(String a, String b, Map<String, String> c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

}
```

You could also create a static method returning the correct value. Note that the method needs to be static because you can't call an instance method inside `this()`.

```
public class Foo {

    public Foo(String a, String b) {
        this(a, b, getDefaultMap());
    }

    public Foo(String a, String b, Map<String, String> c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getDefaultMap() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("x", "y");
        map.put("f", "g");
        return map;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HashMap` method `.put` returns a `String` so you are passing a `String` when calling the 3 argument constructor in your 2 argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick like this:

```
public Foo(String a, String b) {
    this(a, b, new HashMap<String, String>(){
       {
           put("x", "y");
           put("f", "g");
       }
    });
}
```

It creates anonymous class that inherits HashMap and defines init block with putting values.

Comment: This is called double-brace initialization but I'm not sure if I would recommend it.

Comment: Yes but do note that it creates an anonymous inner class. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1958636/1743880).

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the "call to this() must be the first statement" by adding a **static** method that creates your default `Map` instance:

```
public Foo(String a, String b) {
    this(a, b, createDefaultMap());
}

private static Map<String, String> createDefaultMap() {
    Map<String, String> defaultMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    defaultMap.put("x", "y");
    defaultMap.put("f", "g");

    return defaultMap;
}
```

It is mandatory that `createDefaultMap()` is static, as you may not access the half-constructed instance at this point.